# Save exif information to texture2d with unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, exif

I would like to save exif information to photos taken using webcamtexture and save them.

But I do not know how to save EXIF information.
I want to save a JPG file with GPS position information set.

How can I do it?

```
var tex = new Texture2D(rt.width, rt.height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false, false);
RenderTexture.active = photoRenderTexture;

tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, rt.width, rt.height), 0, 0);
tex.Apply();

RenderTexture.active = null;
photoCamera.targetTexture = null;

byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
Object.Destroy(tex);

string path = Application.temporaryCachePath + "/pic.png";
File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768571/exif-lat-long-from-image-in-unity